# dvips: ! Bad PK file

Tags: texlive, cjk

Here is my latex code:

```
\documentclass{ctexart}
\begin{document}
中文宏包测试
\end{document}
```

I install the ctex and zhmetrics with Texlive, but I still get the error message:
`dvips: ! Bad PK file /home/jerry/texmf/fonts/pk/modeless/zhmetrics/gbksong/gbksong51.9640pk: unexpected eof`
 I cannot find the where it goes wrong. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Which error message? Please provide the complete error message and some minimal, and complete example code producing this error.

Comment: @Gonzalo: I think the one in the title: "! Bad PK file". It is better to repeat this information in the body.

Comment: While I have no knowledge of Chinese, you might find a [google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=gbksong51.9640pk%3A+unexpected+eof&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#sclient=psy&hl=en&safe=active&client=firefox-a&hs=Bc7&rls=org.mozilla:en-US%3Aofficial&q=gbksong+unexpected+eof&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=5153d77f78fc9410) of the font and error helpful.  It seems others have had this problem before.

Comment: Which engine are you using, xelatex or pdftex? For xelatex, ctex uses xeCJK; while for others ctex uses CJK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a developer of `ctex` package, I'd say: `ctex` does NOT support `latex`+`dvips` approach by default. And `zhmetrics` does not provide mapping files for `ttf2pk` to create PK fonts on the fly.

When compiling with `latex` command, `ctex` package uses `zhmetrics` with default `zhmap` option. Then `zhwinfonts.tex` is used and TrueType font mappings are configured for dvipdfmx only. And when compiling with `pdflatex` command, TureType font mappings are configured for pdfTeX. Dvips do not support this, and we do not support dvips.

You can only use one of these to compile your documents:

- `latex` + `dvipdfmx`
- `pdflatex`
- `xelatex`

---

If you insist on dvips, you must use `ttf2pt1` or `fontforge` to convert the TrueType fonts to type 1 format. Then write a font mapping file and use `updmap` utility to install them.

Or, you can write proper `ttfonts.map` to get bitmap fonts on the fly.

After that, you can use `ctexart` with `nozhmap` option to use type 1 or PK fonts. (It is illegal as I know.)

Type 1 Chinese fonts are only useful for MetaPost. It is not recommended to use type 1 fonts.

Answer (score 2):

The error message:

```
dvips: ! Bad PK file /home/jerry/texmf/fonts/pk/modeless/zhmetrics/gbksong/gbksong51.9640pk: unexpected eof
```

indicates that the mentioned file is not complete, i.e. some part is missing at the end of the file (eof). This could easily happened when the copy process of the file was interrupted during installation. Simply reinstall the file and it should work.